# Visual Studio 2013 not detecting TypeScript references

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013

I'm having an issue where opening a TypeScript file causes Visual Studio to show an error on any jQuery selectors, however, on build it compiles my typescript just fine. My best guess is that VS isn't implicitly referencing typings files. If I include a reference path it seems to resolve the issue, however I know this isn't how it's supposed to work.

I've looked around and haven't found anyone who's experiencing a similar problem other then this [post](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1855), which sadly was not a solution for me. I'm at a loss as to how I would go about fixing this.

I'm running Visual Studio Premium 2013 and TypeScript 0.9.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is amusing. I created a new TypeScript file and all my errors went away.

Comment: Just wait... They'll come back!

Comment: Just keep making more TypeScript files! :D

Answer (score 1):

check the visual studio plugins you have installed. MySQL Connector for Visual Studio caused weird bugs for me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue myself when I upgraded to TypeScript 0.9.5.  Whilst implicit referencing is working just fine for compilation the TypeScript Language Service (that provides intellisense / highlighting etc) is toast.

If you take a look way down in the comments [here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1995) you can feel my pain.

The way round it I found was to create a _references.ts file (details of that can be read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx)) which contains all the TypeScript files in my project.  It's a bit of a pain but it seems to make the TypeScript Language Service happy again.

It's really frustrating that the TS Language Service and the standard compilation of TS have different experiences - hopefully this will be resolved before TS 1.0 hits the shelves.

I've logged this an issue on the TypeScript CodePlex site here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2071

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of strange errors with VS and TS. Sometimes you can delete a ; and add it back and lots of "bad" references/red squiggles go away. I think this is "growing pains" for typescript in VS.